# ngrx effects error handling

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

I have a very basic question concerning @ngrx effects: How to ignore an error that happens during the execution of an effect such that it doesn't affect future effect execution?

My situation is as follows: I have an action (LOGIN) and an effect listening to that action. If an error happens inside this effect, I want to ignore it. When LOGIN is dispatched a second time after this error, the effect should be executed a second time.

My first attempt to do this was:

```
  @Effect()
  login$ = this.actions$
    .ofType('LOGIN')
    .flatMap(async () => {
      console.debug('LOGIN');
      // throw an error
      let x = [];x[0]();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Error at login', err);
      return Observable.empty();
    });
```

Dispatching LOGIN the first time throws and catches the error, as expected. However, if I dispatch LOGIN a second time afterwards, nothing happens; the effect is not executed.

Therefore I tried the following:

```
    .catch(err => {
      return this.login$;
    });
```

, but this results in an endless loop... Do you know how to catch the error without preventing effect execution afterwards?

Comment: I don't know ngrx but you can probably just `.retry()` on the stream instead of catching.

Comment: What is the version of ngrx u were using ?
I tried this with latest version of ngrx, seems its not working..

Versions, I am using now:
  "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
  "@ngrx/effects": "^6.1.2",
        "@ngrx/entity": "^6.1.2",
        "@ngrx/store": "^6.1.2",

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `ngrx` infrastructure subscribes to the effect via the provider imported into the app's `NgModule` using `EffectsModule.run`.

When the observable errors and `catch` returns a empty obervable, the composed observable completes and its subscribers are unsubscribed - that's part of the [*Observable Contract*](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html). And that's the reason you see no further handling of `LOGIN` actions in your effect. The effect is unsubscribed on completion and the `ngrx` infrastructure does not re-subscribe.

Typically, you would have the error handling inside the `flatMap` (now called `mergeMap`):

```ts
import { Actions, Effect, toPayload } from "@ngrx/effects";

@Effect()
login$ = this.actions$
  .ofType('LOGIN')
  .map(toPayload)
  .flatMap(payload => Observable
    .from(Promise.reject('Boom!'))
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error at login', error);
      return Observable.empty();
    })
  });
```

The `catch` composed into the inner observable will see an empty observable flattened/merged into the effect, so no action will be emitted.

Answer (score 8):

The `@Effect` stream is *completing* when the error occurs, preventing any further actions.

The solution is to switch to a disposable stream. If an error occurs within the disposable stream it's okay, as the main `@Effect` stream always stays alive, and future actions continue to execute.

```
@Effect()
login$ = this.actions$
    .ofType('LOGIN')
    .switchMap(action => {

        // This is the disposable stream!
        // Errors can safely occur in here without killing the original stream

        return Rx.Observable.of(action)
            .map(action => {
                // Code here that throws an error
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // You could also return an 'Error' action here instead
                return Observable.empty();
            });

    });
```

More info on this technique in this blog post: [The Quest for Meatballs: Continue RxJS Streams When Errors Occur](https://iamturns.com/continue-rxjs-streams-when-errors-occur/?ref=so&refId=41685519)

Answer (score 1):

this is how I handle the option to be notified or not notified on Observables that didn't find any data:

```
 public listenCampaignValueChanged(emitOnEmpty: boolean = false): Observable<CampaignsModelExt> {
        var campaignIdSelected$ = this.ngrxStore.select(store => store.appDb.uiState.campaign.campaignSelected)
        var campaigns$ = this.ngrxStore.select(store => store.msDatabase.sdk.table_campaigns);
        return campaignIdSelected$
            .combineLatest(campaigns$, (campaignId: number, campaigns: List<CampaignsModelExt>) => {
                return campaigns.find((i_campaign: CampaignsModelExt) => {
                    return i_campaign.getCampaignId() == campaignId;
                });
            }).flatMap(v => (v ? Observable.of(v) : ( emitOnEmpty ? Observable.of(v) : Observable.empty())));
    }
```