# dispatch multiple actions in one effect

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I would like to dispatch two actions in one effect.
Currently I have to declare two effects to achieve this :

```ts
// first effect
@Effect()
action1$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(CoreActionTypes.MY_ACTION)
  .map(res => {
    return { type: "ACTION_ONE"}
  })
  .catch(() => Observable.of({
    type: CoreActionTypes.MY_ACTION_FAILED
  }));

// second effect
@Effect()
action2$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(CoreActionTypes.MY_ACTION)
  .map(res => {
    return { type: "ACTION_TWO"}
  })
  .catch(() => Observable.of({
    type: CoreActionTypes.MY_ACTION_FAILED
  }));
```

Is it possible to have one action, be the source of two actions via a single effect?

Comment: FYI, with `catch` composed where it is in your effect, if an error occurs, the observable will complete and your effect will cease to work. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41685689/6680611).

Answer (score 73):

```js
@Effect()
loadInitConfig$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(layout.ActionTypes.LOAD_INIT_CONFIGURATION)
    .map<Action, void>(toPayload)
    .switchMap(() =>
        this.settingsService
            .loadInitConfiguration()
            .mergeMap((data: any) => [
                new layout.LoadInitConfigurationCompleteAction(data.settings),
                new meetup.LoadInitGeolocationCompleteAction(data.geolocation)
            ])
            .catch(error =>
                Observable.of(
                    new layout.LoadInitConfigurationFailAction({
                        error
                    })
                )
            )
    );
```

Comment: This one is really helpful!

Comment: How about the  execute sequence these 2 actions processed by reducer?

Comment: That's the first time I've seen `mergeMap` project function returning an array! Brilliant answer

Comment: This is an anti pattern, according to Mike Ryan the co-founder of ngrx. https://twitter.com/MikeRyanDev/status/938108618133602304

Comment: hi, yes i know, but sometimes an anti-pattern it's not  a bad solution

Comment: This is opinionated, and sometimes it is totally fine to dispatch multiple actions from the same effect, if you know exactly what is affected.

Comment: Returning multiple actions is a nono. Instead you should look into this eslint plugin how it should be done: https://github.com/timdeschryver/eslint-plugin-ngrx/blob/main/docs/rules/no-multiple-actions-in-effects.md

Answer (score 19):

You can use `switchMap` and `Observable.of`.

```
 @Effect({ dispatch: true }) action$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(CoreActionTypes.MY_ACTION)
    .switchMap(() => Observable.of(
        // subscribers will be notified
        {type: 'ACTION_ONE'} ,
        // subscribers will be notified (again ...)
        {type: 'ACTION_TWO'}
    ))
    .catch(() => Observable.of({
      type: CoreActionTypes.MY_ACTION_FAILED
    }));
```

**Performance matters :**

Instead of dispatching many actions that will **trigger all the subscribers as many times as you dispatch**, you may want to take a look into [redux-batched-actions](https://github.com/tshelburne/redux-batched-actions).

This allows you to warn your subscribers only when all of those multiple actions have been applied to the store.

For example :

```
@Effect({ dispatch: true }) action$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(CoreActionTypes.MY_ACTION)
    // subscribers will be notified only once, no matter how many actions you have
    // not between every action
    .map(() => batchActions([
        doThing(),
        doOther()
    ]))
    .catch(() => Observable.of({
      type: CoreActionTypes.MY_ACTION_FAILED
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I test the multiple returned actions ?

Answer (score 13):

If anyone wonders how to mix plain actions with ones from Observables.

I was stuck with same task, but small difference: I needed to dispatch two actions, with second one after API call, which made it an Observable. Something like:

1. `action1` is just an action: `{type: 'ACTION_ONE'}`
2. `action2` is API call mapped to action: `Observable<{type: 'ACTION_TWO'}>`

Following code solved my issue:

```
@Effect() action$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(CoreActionTypes.MY_ACTION),
    mergeMap(res =>
        // in order to dispatch actions in provided order
        concat(
            of(action1),
            action2
        )
    ),
    catchError(() => Observable.of({
        type: CoreActionTypes.MY_ACTION_FAILED
    }))
);
```

[concat doc's](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html)

Comment: I was in a similar scenario and using `concat` did the work, thanks.
My scenario:

`
@Effect() action$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(CoreActionTypes.MY_ACTION),
    mergeMap( ( { payload } ) =>
      this.dialog
        .open(DialogComponent)
        .afterClosed()
        .pipe(
          switchMap((resp) => concat( of( action1 ), action2  ) )
        )
    )
  );
`

Comment: Thanks, I suspected it's doable, but my rxjs knowledge was not strong enough. This worked perfectly

Answer (score 6):

You can choose `mergeMap` for async or `concatMap` for sync

```
  @Effect() action$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(CoreActionTypes.MY_ACTION)
    .mergeMap(() => Observable.from([{type: "ACTION_ONE"} , {type: "ACTION_TWO"}]))
    .catch(() => Observable.of({
      type: CoreActionTypes.MY_ACTION_FAILED
    }));
```

Comment: The main problem with this answer is a performance problem (which might just be acceptable) but also a consistency problem, which might be a big deal. If you split your actions and have a normalized state, dispatching 2 actions without using batched actions might end up into a store inconsistency and some selectors of your app might end up with errors.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use .do() and store.next()

do allows you to attach a callback to the observable without affecting the other operators / changing the observable

e.g.

```
@Effect() action1$ = this.actions$
.ofType(CoreActionTypes.MY_ACTION)
.do(myaction => this.store.next( {type: 'ACTION_ONE'} ))
.switchMap((myaction) => Observable.of(
    {type: 'ACTION_TWO'}
))
.catch(() => Observable.of({
  type: CoreActionTypes.MY_ACTION_FAILED
}));
```

(you will need a reference to the store in your effects class)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much Jus. I'm learning this library and your example helped me fire multiple actions synchronously

Answer (score 1):

How about using `flatMap` as below with ngrx `8.3.0` version syntax of `effects` and `actions`:

```
  someEffect$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(CoreActionTypes.MY_ACTION),
      flatMap((data) => [
        CoreActionTypes.MY_ACTION_2(data),
        CoreActionTypes.MY_ACTION_3(data),
      ])
    )
  );
```

Comment: This is an anti pattern, according to Mike Ryan the co-founder of ngrx. https://twitter.com/MikeRyanDev/status/938108618133602304

Comment: @callback: Thanks for letting me know. I'll dig more into it. This practice was proposed by Victor Savkin in https://youtu.be/FQ6fzkHvCEY?t=1019 (splitter actions)

Comment: isn't `of` operator required to wrap the multiple actions?

Comment: `flatMap` has been deprecated, so can be achievable by `mergeMap`