# ngrx - handling errors in reducer and effect

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Having a play around using ngrx with the effects module. I'm dispatching an action, doing some async stuff via an effect, then I'm dispatching a new action to update the state, then redirect. Here's a cut down version of what i'm doing:

```
@Injectable()
export class Effects {

  @Effect()
  start$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType('start')
    // omitted for brevity
    .concatMap(action => [
      new finishAction(action.payload),
      go(['/'])
    ])
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('err', err);
      return Observable.empty();
    })

  constructor(private actions$: Actions) {
  }
}
```

This all works fine - when i dispatch a `start` action, this effect kicks in, dispatches a `finish` action, then redirects back to the root (via the `go` action which is imported from `@ngrx/router-store`.

How do I handle something failing in `finishAction` ? At the moment i get an error in the console and then `go` runs regardless.

Ideally i'd like to intercept this failure, and dispatch another action (so i can show a modal or something, but not do the redirect)

Comment: Note that catching errors with the approach you are using in the snippet will see your effect observable complete and no actions will be handled after an error. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/41685689/6680611

Answer (score 0):

If the finishAction's reducer fails the process the action the state should be changed to the error one.

You can subscribe to Effects.start$ in your component and select the error state. If the subscription receives the error you can react by moving to a new route.

Comment: thanks for the response. that's not happening though - if the finishAction errors in the code i've posted above, the "go" action still runs

Comment: u can move 'go code to Effects.start$.withLatestFrom(state).subscribe(x=>if(x=='good result') go('"/good") else go("/bad")})