# ngrx/effects - How to test with a promise

Tags: ngrx-effects

I'm using ngrx/effects with marbles testing. I have a service that uses promises. I want my effect to call the service and handle both successful and error states. I have code like this

Effect:

`.mergeMap(() =>
  this.service.getThings()
    .map((things) => new SetThingsAction(things))
      .catch((error) =>
        of(new HandleAPIErrorAction(error))
      )
    )
  .catch((error) =>
    of(new HandleAPIErrorAction(error))
  );`

Service:

  `public geThings() {
    return Observable.fromPromise(this.promiseBasedThing.getTheThings());
  }`

Then a test:

    `actions = hot("a", { a: new GetThingsAction() });
    const response = cold("-#", {});
    service.getThings.and.returnValue( response );
    const expected = cold("-b", { b: new HandleAPIErrorAction("error") });
    expect(effects.getThings$).toBeObservable(expected);`

This actually all works. However the double catch in the effect seems clearly bad and probably suggests I don't understand how Observables work.   In the real world only the later catch is effective. In a test the first is effective.

Based on [this](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/498) it seems like Promises don't work with marbles tests. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41685519/ngrx-effects-error-handling) gives an idea on error handling but it seems impossible to test because it has a Promise.

How can I use ngrx/effects with error handling, promises, and testing.

Answer (score 2):

Can answer my own after further research.

https://jsfiddle.net/btroncone/upy6nr6n/

Basically I needed to do the catch in the getThings instead of in the effect.

```
 getThings() {
    return Observable.fromPromise(this.promiseBasedThing.getTheThings())
      .catch((error) => Observable.of(error));
  }
```

Also learned that it's much easier to solve these problems with a simple rsjx example instead of trying to solve it while using ngrx/effects too. This still has two catch statements, but the test mocking now matches how it works in reality.