# How to implement a global ErrorHandler along with an HttpInterceptor in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-http-interceptors, angular-errorhandler

I found on the web that ErrorHandler can catch all errors as client-side errors and also `httpErrorResponse` errors.

But in my situation, I can catch only client-side errors in GlobalErrorHandlerService, the other one `httpErrorResponse` can't be caught.
What did I do wrong?

**My app-module:**

```
providers: [
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MainInterceptorService, multi: true },

 { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandlerService  },
],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**My GlobalErrorHandler:**

```
import {ErrorHandler, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpErrorResponse} from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GlobalErrorHandlerService implements ErrorHandler{

  constructor() { }

  handleError(error: any): void {
    console.log("Handler work")
    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse){

      console.log("HttpErrorResponse")
    } else {
      console.log("Not httpErrorResponse")
    }
 }
}
```

**My interceptor:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from "@angular/common/http";
import {catchError, Observable, throwError} from "rxjs";
import {error} from "@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/util";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MainInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor{
  private httpError = {
    status: 0,
    message: ''
  };

  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // req=req.clone({headers:req.headers.set("Auth","Bearer"+token)})

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError(
        (error:HttpErrorResponse|Error)=>{

      // server-side error
          if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse){
            console.log("intercepter work")
            return throwError(()=>new Error("Server side error"+error));
          } else {
            return throwError(()=>new Error("Client side error"+error))
          }
        }
     )
    )
  }
}
```

**My UserService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from "@angular/common/http";
import {User} from "../entity/user";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  errors:any[]|undefined
  private response:Response|undefined

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  readonly URL_BASE="http://****"
  readonly URL_REGISTRATE="http://****"

  registrUser(user:User):any {

    return this.http.post<any>(this.URL_BASE+"/account/register", user)
  }

  loginUser(userName:string,password:string):any{

    return this.http.post<any>(this.URL_BASE+"/account/signin",{userName,password})
  }
}
```

If you explain the logic of ErrorHandler then it will be really a pleasure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I now understand what's happening in your code:

- **First** your `MainInterceptorService` gets called. If you get a server-error, you convert the `HttpErrorResponse` into a `Error`-object.
- **Second**, your `GlobalErrorHandlerService` gets hit, but since you already converted your error into an object of type `Error`, it will no longer be recognized as `HttpErrorResponse` and therefore it get's treated as client-side-error.
- What I also noticed: When I added a `catchError()` inside `registrUser()` or `loginUser()`, the `GlobalErrorHandlerService` was **not** hit anymore for these methods, because the local `catchError()` swallowed the errors (yet I could have rethrown the errors to trigger the `GlobalErrorHandlerService` nevertheless ;-))

Therefore our goal must be to refactor `MainInterceptorService` in a way that it doesn't convert the original error-type to a different kind of object. This can be done as follows:

```
export class MainInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // req=req.clone({headers:req.headers.set("Auth","Bearer"+token)})

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError(
        (err: HttpErrorResponse|Error)=>{
          if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse){
            console.error('Server side error'+err);
          } else {
            console.error('Not a httpErrorResponse'+err);
          }
          return throwError(() => err);
        }
     )
    );
  }
}
```

**Important:**

- You can actually forget about the code-suggestion I made in my previous answer. Just leave everything as it is apart from the `MainInterceptorService`-code I showed above.
- Be aware that client-side errors might not enter the `HttpInterceptor`, since often times they are not related to a http-request.
- You basically use `ErrorHandler` to handle client-side errors and `HttpInterceptors` to handle errors related to http-requests.
- Under the following link you can find an example on what an error-related `HttpInterceptor` could look like: [Global ErrorHandler is not working after implementing catchError in ngrx effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54765185/global-errorhandler-is-not-working-after-implementing-catcherror-in-ngrx-effect)

Comment: So your problem is solved now? Or do you still have any open questions concerning error-handling?

Comment: Nope, look at my code in GlobalErrorHandler. I can't to get "Handler work" message when I'm getting server side HttpErrorResponse instance.

Comment: I don't know why, cause I implemented correctly and provided at AppModule. Hovewer he doesn't work and i can't to gather all errors together by that issue

Comment: OK, I now updated my answer. I tried your code in my own project and I think I found out what the problem was.

Comment: Yes, you rescued me. All work but I change two files. I deleted the error in MainInterceptionService and added CatchError instead how you said before and second file which you showed above. Thank you for help. Congratulation with Happy New Year!!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :-). Happy new year to you too :-).